# Regresar a estilos después de onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

Necesito una ayuda, tengo un boton que al darle click cambia la clase de un div, inicialmente ".bas" a ".activate," Para aplicar una animacion.
¿Como puedo hacer que despues del onclick, cambiar la clase y ejecutar la animacion la caja vuelva a .bas?
Mi codigo JS:

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
boton.onclick = basico;
function basico(){
    let  ataque = document.getElementById("move")
    ataque.className = "activate";
}
```

Comment: No adjuntas nada de tú código ni de la supuesta "animación". Tampoco queda claro si cómo tal la "animación" es una animación o una transición de css. De cualquier manera prueba agregando al final de  la función `basico` algo como: `ataque.onanimationend = (e) => e.target.classList.remove("activate")`. Si no te funciona prueba cambiando el evento a `.transitionend` en lugar de `.onanimationend`

Answer (score 0):

encontre quizas una solucion a tu problema te dejo el codigo:

```js
/* Script */

var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
 var base = document.querySelector('.base');
    boton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    base.classList.toggle('dark');
 });
```

```css
/* Estilos css*/
.base{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.dark{
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- Contenido HTML -->
<button id="boton">
  Cambiar
</button>
<div class="base">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No se cuanto dura tu animacion, pero si sabes el tiempo, le puedes hacer un setTimeout y despues devolverle la clase original.

JS

```
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
    boton.addEventListener("click", basico);

function basico(){
  bas =  document.querySelector(".base");
  bas.className = "animacion";
    
    tiempo = setTimeout(tiempo,2000);
}
function tiempo(){
document.querySelector(".animacion").className = "base";
    
}
```

HTML

```
    <button id="boton">
        Cambiar
      </button>
      <div class="base">
      </div>
```